# Merge statement renamed columns with a single quote, error in renaming column in python pandas datafarame

Tags: python, pandas, rename

Here is the data after it's been through a merge
[image: here here]
This is the rename code that isn't working

```
data_renamed = data.rename(columns={
    "('MonthCompletionXWSWeighting', 'sum')": "MonthCompletionXWSWeighting",
    "('Actual / Plan', '')": "Actual / Plan", 
    "('Month', '')": "Month", 
    "('#', '')": "#"   
    }, inplace=True)

data_renamed.dtype
```

Comment: Rather than fixing this mess, can't you avoid making it on the first place? What are the dataframes before the merge?

Comment: Good question @mozway. Why does the Merge statement change the column names? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Is it a Multiindex? Hard to tell with an image. Please provide the data as *text*, and , ideally the input data before the merge and the merge command.

Comment: can you post the output of `df.columns` after merging?

Answer (score 2):

Let's try list comprehension in case you have lot of columns:

```
data_renamed.columns=[x.strip("()").replace("'",'').split(',')[0] for x in data_renamed]
```

Sample Dateframe used:

```
cols=["('MonthCompletionXWSWeighting', 'sum')", "('Actual / Plan', '')", "('Month', '')", "('#', '')"]
data_renamed=pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
```

Comment: I didn't realize that a merge operation in python yields a tuple, not a dataframe. I tried this instead : data_renamed = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Actual / Plan', '#','Month','MonthCompletionXWSWeighting'])

Answer (score 1):

You better just declare the new column names (by their order of apperance):

```
data_renamed.columns = ["Actual / Plan", "#", "Month", "MonthCompletionXWSWeighting"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize that a merge operation in python yields a tuple, not a dataframe. I tried this instead :  `data_renamed = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Actual / Plan', '#','Month','MonthCompletionXWSWeighting'])`